# Simplify the graph keeping connectivity

Tags: algorithm, matlab, graph

I have some fully connected graph in Matlab. I want to remove small edges iteratively. If removing of some edge will destroy the graph connectivity, then I would like to keep this edge and try to remove next one.
I have a Matlab code, which perfectly do it:

```
close all
clear all
clc
rng(2023)
%% generate fake data
X = rand(100,10);
R = corr(X);
R = (R+R')./2; % remove numerical problems. Make matrix symmetric
G = graph(R.^2,'omitselfloops');
%% simplify the graph
G.Edges.isChecked(:)=0;
G.Edges.edgeID=[1:size(G.Edges,1)]';
while true
    
    % find minimal edge, which is not checked already
    notCheckedEdges = G.Edges(G.Edges.isChecked==0,:);
    [~,minID] = min(notCheckedEdges.Weight);
    minID = notCheckedEdges.edgeID(minID); % substitute to original ID
    % remove minimal edges
    G1 = rmedge(G,find(G.Edges.edgeID==minID));
    % check if graph is still connected
    isConnected = numel(unique(conncomp(G1)))==1;
    if isConnected
        G = G1; % remove edge
    else
        G.Edges.isChecked(G.Edges.edgeID==minID)=1; % mark edges as checked and keep it for next iterations
    end
    if all(G.Edges.isChecked==1), break; end % terminate loop when all edges were checked
end
```

The problem is that this code is very slow and primitive.

**Do you know how to improve my code or maybe some ready to use algorithm?**

Comment: The graph you end up with is a maximum weight spanning tree.  There are fast ways to find it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992664/how-to-find-maximum-spanning-tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks too Matt Timmermans comment. All I need is:

```
G = graph(1-R.^2,'omitselfloops');
G = minspantree(G);
```